Playwright framework
How do I start learningg Playwright framework
I have basic knowledge about Programming languages like Java
I am already using Java based framework - RESTASSURED API automation framework
hands on experience in using Jenkins and azure cicd pipeline setup
please advise and suggest few tips which will help me to learn this framework in 2-3 Months.
Downloaded the framework from GITHUB and tried to understand the folder structure
